# What are the best practices to follow for multi-region failover when there are SQS messages queued in the failing region?

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-sqs, high-availability, failover, disaster-recovery

Assume that I have a full-stack replicated and running on two geographical regions A and B, and the ELB application of region A has fallen for some reason, so we need to redirect all traffic to region B. Assuming that there are messages queued in the SQS of region A, what are some good practices to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Amazon SNS to fan out messages to multi SQS queues, even in multiple different regions.  Details here: [Sending Amazon SNS messages to an Amazon SQS queue or AWS Lambda function in a different Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-cross-region-delivery.html)